# Control_L + Shift_L + t not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xfce, keyboard-layout, gentoo

I'm running gentoo & xfec4 (4.12-r1).

`Control_L` + `Shift_L` + `t` does not work

`Control_R` + `Shift_R` + `t` works

`Control_L` + `Shift_R` + `t` works

`Control_R` + `Shift_L` + `t` works

Looking at `xev` `lctl` and `lshift` both generate output, but nothing when I press `t` with those modifier keys.  Any other modifier combination above generates output on `t` press.  I have not tested this in the conlole.

I have checked my keyboard shortcuts and this combination is not mapped.

**Any suggestions to fix this?**  Thanks

```
0 blaze /home/brundage % xmodmap
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Here's output from `xev`

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x1e8, subw 0x0, time 658689015, (-431,49), root:(440,1281),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x1e8, subw 0x0, time 658689552, (-431,49), root:(440,1281),
    state 0x14, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x1e8, subw 0x0, time 658694240, (-431,49), root:(440,1281),
    state 0x15, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x1e8, subw 0x0, time 658694560, (-431,49), root:(440,1281),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Guess: Some other application triggers on Control_L + Shift_L and intercepts this combination. Do you get Focus events in `xev` when pressing Control_L + Shift_L? Or anything else that looks different from the other combinations?

Comment: @dirkt Nothing. Aside from the `t` key press event registering in the three worikng cases, the `xev` output is the same. Edited the question with output from the busted case.

Comment: Hm. Interesting. Is this effect restricted to `t`, or does it happen to every key?

Comment: Went through the letter keys. `g`, `l`, & `t` exhibit this behavior.

Comment: I recommend creating a test user and therefore a clean home directory / Xfce configuration. If the issue does not occur there, then at least it is narrowed down to something in your home directory.

Comment: If it's not all keys, but just three, then I'd definitely suspect something else that reacts on those three. The usual suspects are `ibus` or the WM, so a test user with a clean xfce configuration might be a good idea.

Comment: Set up a test user and saw the same behavior. I'm not using `ibus`, but `dbus` is running. Here's what I do have running. https://pastebin.com/5fJG3Cpy